# Eclipse console not working properly, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: eclipse, console

In my eclipse console in missed and that not work correctly

I try to minimize that and slowly slowly that will missed the console
I want mu eclipse back normalli
Please try to back it. Please try to that get it back yo mee in my eclipse
Can u try to send a back too me plzzz